# Do not scale stroke on resize (keep stroke consistent) AfterEffects | Expression Method

Tags: expression, after-effects

The goal of this is to keep the stroke width the same when scaling in the transform method of a shape layer. so for example, a 200% scale would result in the same stroke width as 100% etc. Any & all ideas on how to accomplish this more efficiently are appreciated!

EQUATION:
scale = scale/100 
stroke = stroke
Value = stroke/scale >>> the abs value is used on scale so it works with positive and negative values.

In Aftereffects:

```
strokeSize = DESIRED;

try {strokeSize / Math.abs(thisLayer.parent.transform.scale[0]/100)} 
catch{strokeSize / Math.abs(transform.scale[0]/100)};
```

Explanation - try to use the parented layer for scale else, "catch" & use the version which applies the current layer's scale instead.

Right now applying this to a bunch of layers is annoying even with the edit "copy expression only". Open to alternative ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Over the years I found 3 different versions of this method on Reddit and Twitter.

1:

```
value / length(toComp([0,0]), toComp([0.7071,0.7071])) || 0.001;
```

2:

```
scaleFactor = length(toComp([0,0]),toComp([1,0]));
value / scaleFactor || 0.001;
```

3:

```
value*(100/transform.scale[0]);
```

Pretty useful stuff :)